# AVCam: Building a Camera App - Draw a grid on top of PreviewView

Tags: swift, uiview, camera, avfoundation, avcam

I've downloaded AVCam app sample from Apple.
I added a custom view "GridView" on top of PreviewView, but i would like to size my GridView in order draw my grid on top of the captured image.

How can i get the bound of the capture image?

thanks

[image]

Comment: PreviewMetalView does not exits in AVCam sample project

Comment: I mistook it with AVCamFilter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**1- Create a gird**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GridView: UIView
{
    private var path = UIBezierPath()
    fileprivate var gridWidthMultiple: CGFloat
    {
        return 4
    }
    fileprivate var gridHeightMultiple : CGFloat
    {
        return 4
    }

    fileprivate var gridWidth: CGFloat
    {
        return bounds.width/CGFloat(gridWidthMultiple)
    }

    fileprivate var gridHeight: CGFloat
    {
        return bounds.height/CGFloat(gridHeightMultiple)
    }

    fileprivate var gridCenter: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
    }

    fileprivate func drawGrid()
    {
        path = UIBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = 2.0

        for index in 1...Int(gridWidthMultiple) - 1
        {
            let start = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index) * gridWidth, y: 0)
            let end = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index) * gridWidth, y:bounds.height)
            path.move(to: start)
            path.addLine(to: end)
        }

        for index in 1...Int(gridHeightMultiple) - 1 {
            let start = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(index) * gridHeight)
            let end = CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: CGFloat(index) * gridHeight)
            path.move(to: start)
            path.addLine(to: end)
        }

        //Close the path.
        path.close()

    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        drawGrid()

        // Specify a border (stroke) color.
        UIColor.systemYellow.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**2- In ViewController**

define a grid var:

```
var gridView: GridView!
```

```
func addGrid() {
    gridView = GridView(frame: previewView.bounds)
    previewView.addSubview(gridView)
}
```

Add call addGrid in viewdidLoad or anywhere that suits you.

Then we need to update the frame of the gridView based on the displayed camera live view.

```
func updateGrid() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let p1 = self.previewView.videoPreviewLayer.layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint: .zero)
        let p2 = self.previewView.videoPreviewLayer.layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1))
            
        self.gridView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: p1.y, width: p1.x, height: p2.y - p1.y)
            
    }
}
```

You call call updateGrid wherever best suits in your case. In here I called it in viewWillAppear after the session starts running:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        sessionQueue.async {
            switch self.setupResult {
            case .success:
                // Only setup observers and start the session if setup succeeded.
                self.addObservers()
                self.session.startRunning()
                self.isSessionRunning = self.session.isRunning
                
                self.updateGrid()
                
                
            case .notAuthorized:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let changePrivacySetting = "AVCam doesn't have permission to use the camera, please change privacy settings"
                    let message = NSLocalizedString(changePrivacySetting, comment: "Alert message when the user has denied access to the camera")
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "AVCam", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Alert OK button"),
                                                            style: .cancel,
                                                            handler: nil))
                    
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Settings", comment: "Alert button to open Settings"),
                                                            style: .`default`,
                                                            handler: { _ in
                                                                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!,
                                                                                          options: [:],
                                                                                          completionHandler: nil)
                    }))
                    
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                
            case .configurationFailed:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alertMsg = "Alert message when something goes wrong during capture session configuration"
                    let message = NSLocalizedString("Unable to capture media", comment: alertMsg)
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "AVCam", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Alert OK button"),
                                                            style: .cancel,
                                                            handler: nil))
                    
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: very exhaustive reply, thx.

Comment: Did it answer your question?